# Contribution of major nutrients to energy in the human body

Tags: metabolism, human-physiology

What is the contribution of the major nutrients -- glucose, fat and protein -- to the human body's energy requirements, in normal conditions?

For some tissues, the fuel preference is known qualitatively -- the brain runs on glucose, the heart preferentially oxidizes fatty acids, etc. I'm looking for *quantitative* data on the consumption (oxidation) rate of the major nutrients, on the whole-body level. Molar amounts per unit time, or energy per unit time, or relative contributions to the total.

To get a rough idea, I looked at glucose and triglyceride turnover in blood. [This article](http://diabetes.diabetesjournals.org/content/26/11/1005) estimates blood glucose turnover at about 8 g / hour, or 190 g / day. If we assume that blood glucose transport equals amount of oxidized glucose, then this corresponds to 3200 kJ / day, or about 1/3 of the daily energy requirement. Similarly, [this article](http://www.jlr.org/content/47/1/99.full.pdf) estimates blood triglyceride half-life at about 1h; with a blood triglyceride content about 5 g, this yields about 90 g / day, or 3300 kJ / day from fat.

So with this rough estimate, sugar and fat appears about equally important, but about 1/3 of the daily energy requirement is missing. And I would imagine my quick calculation is inaccurate in many ways... Anyone know of better estimates? Some literature on the subject?

(I'm aware of the the [dietary reference intake data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dietary_Reference_Intake), but diet composition may not equal the proportions of nutrients oxidized due to all sorts of interconversions.)

Comment: Good question... depends on what "normal conditions" is defined as... even during a 'normal day' the transition from prandial to post-prandial changes the fuel utilization for different tissues of the body

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh  Yes, I realize it may differ with feeding.  I would be happy to learn of any quantitative data, in fed and/or fasted conditions.  Haven't found anything besides by own home-cooked estimates ...